# How to get the size of a Stream after applying a filter by lambda expression?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

Consider the following code:

```
List<Locale> locales = Arrays.asList(
    new Locale("en", "US"),
    new Locale("ar"),
    new Locale("en", "GB")
); 

locales.stream().filter(l -> l.getLanguage() == "en");
```

How do I get the size of the `locales` `ArrayList` **after** applying `filter`, given that `locales.size()` gives me the size **before** applying `filter`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 77, accepted):

When you get a stream from the list, it doesn't modify the list. If you want to get the size of the stream after the filtering, you call `count()` on it.

```
long sizeAfterFilter = 
    locales.stream().filter(l -> l.getLanguage().equals("en")).count();
```

If you want to get a new list, just call `.collect(toList())` on the resulting stream. If you are not worried about modifying the list in place, you can simply use `removeIf` on the `List`.

```
locales.removeIf(l -> !l.getLanguage().equals("en"));
```

Note that `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size list so it'll throw an exception but you can wrap it in an `ArrayList`, or simply collect the content of the filtered stream in a `List` (resp. `ArrayList`) using `Collectors.toList()`(resp. `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`).

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Don't call get() unconditionally, you have no idea whether the stream has elements or not!  Call one of the safe methods -- orElse, orElseThrow, or ifPresent.

Comment: many thanks @BrianGoetz , However there is an instruction before that add element in array if any .

Comment: Count operation closes the stream but I want to further operate on the stream if the size is for example >0.Is there any alternate way to check the size?

Comment: @Niks There may be multiple workarounds. The simplest one would be to first collect the results into a list, check its size and then stream again from that list.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Do not rely on previous code that adds element. At some point in the future someone can change the code and remove this add() line and then your code will fail. Using mentioned method your code is safe no matter someone adds an element or not.

Answer (score 20):

Use the `count()` method:

```
long matches  = locales.stream()
  .filter(l -> l.getLanguage() == "en")
  .count();
```

Note that you are comparing Strings using `==`. Prefer using `.equals()`. While `==` will work when comparing interned Strings, it fails otherwise.

---

FYI it can be coded using only method references:

```
long matches = locales.stream()
  .map(Locale::getLanguage)
  .filter("en"::equals)
  .count();
```

Comment: How would you do it using method reference if you need getCountry as well, so as to differ Brazil from Portugal for example?

Comment: @Philippe because you want to test the locale in different ways, you can’t `map()` then `filter`; you must add a filter that uses a lambda before the map, ie `.filter(location -> location.getCountry().equals("Brazil"))`.